# QtMobility Several QMediaplyers in one applications

Tags: qt

In my program I have to start 5 different videos simultaneously in different QGraphicsVideoitem and loop them. Everything works fine for one player, but if I create two or more then my application doesnt respond after 3 or 2 loops. How can I manage this problem?
Is this problem from API or should I change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing heavy work on other threads so your app will not be frozen?

Some hints:

You can derive your class from [QThread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthread.html), you can use [moveToThread()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#moveToThread) function or if your app is supposed to run on Desktop (instead of mobile) you can consider using [QtConcurrent::run() function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtconcurrentrun.html#run)

Comment: I have tried to create players in other threads. But I had no success.

Comment: Every QMediaplayer I had to setVideoOutput(QGraphicsVideoItem*). But every QGraphicsVideoItem* is added to current scene and it is in Main Gui Thread. So when I use setVideoOutput occurs errors that cant send event to objects from another thread.

Comment: Player renders video in another thread but output gui element is in main thread. This is a collision. I dont have any ideas

Comment: I tried QtConcurrent::run(player,&Myplayr::run) but it doesnt work